# How to valign small pictures within text, so it looks the same for all web-browsers

Tags: css, text, vertical-alignment, image

```
<div style="">How to valign <img src="pictures/qsign.gif" alt="question sign"/>
within text <img src="pictures/qsign.gif" alt="question sign"/>? It looks a bit
different when use different web-browsers.</div>
```

What should I put in style="" to align it vertically? That pictures are rather small, so they look like symbols among the text.
In Opera it looks a bit lower that in Chrome within a text, but I wish it to be exactly by the line of text in any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this or similar with your own class;

```
<style>
.test img { vertical-align:middle;}
</style>
<div class="test">How to valign <img src="pictures/qsign.gif" alt="question sign"/>
within text <img src="pictures/qsign.gif" alt="question sign"/>? It looks a bit
different when use different web-browsers.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

['vertial-align'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) is the CSS property you are looking for.